# Combine Values to Create Bunch of 100

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm, knapsack-problem

suppose I have one array having the values:

```
array(20,40,30,15,60,50,10)
```

Now what i want is to I need to create bunch of 100 or near to hundred.and create separate round for each set of 100(or near to 100).

Say

```
Case 1:
Round 1: array(60,30,10) // 100 or near to 100
Round 2: array(40,50)    // 100 or near to 100
Round 3: array(15,20)    // 100 or near to 100 or remaining

Case 2:
Round 1: array(60,40)    // 100 or near to 100
Round 2: array(50,20,30) // 100 or near to 100
Round 3: array(15,10)    // 100 or near to 100 or remaining
```

So how can I achieve this?

Is there any algorithm regarding this that I can study?

Comment: Check the knapsack problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @Eduardo Knapsack only operates on one bin, but there are multiple here.

Comment: @Jack that is fine. so can't do it for periodically by extracting used and working on remaining ones?

Comment: A possible approximation could be to apply knapsack multiple times I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the [binpacking problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), thus there is no known polynomial solution to solve it.

You can try an exponential approach (check all possibilities) if you need exact. If you want "close enough" you can search the literature for some approximation algorithm, or use some heuristic search solution from the AI field such as [Genetic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).